# Canvas VF page can not find Connected app

Tags: visualforce, canvas

I have a simple VF page to render canvas app. While rendering I am getting error -

> ops, there was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application
>   [MyAppName]. Force.com Canvas can not locate an installed canvas app
>   with the namespace [myNameSpace] and API name [MyAppName].

My VF page is as follows:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:canvasApp applicationname="MyAppName" 
namespacePrefix="myNameSpace"
height="400px" width="100%"/>
</apex:page>
```

I have published my connected app several times. I checked spellings and case sensitivity of the names several times.

I appreciate help in resolving this error.

Answer (score 5):

I could resolve it. I needed to enable OAuth for connected app. I found it weird that I need to enable OAuth even if I do not need it. But well it worked.

Comment: this did the trick for me :D

Comment: Thank you! doesn't make much sense for the signed request flow does it, wasted too much time on this